# Открытие выпадающего списка вне родительского блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dropdown

Есть вот такой вот выпадающий список. Подскажите пожалуйста,как сделать так что бы когда при нажатии он открывался и не растягивал тот блок, в котором он находится, а был как бы поверх этого блока и раскрывался отдельно?

```js
var contacts = ["Jenny Hess", "Elliot Fu", "Stevie Feliciano", "Christian", "Matt"];
$(".wrapperDropdown").append('<ul>');
$(".wrapperDropdown ul").append('<span>');

for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  $(".wrapperDropdown ul").append('<li><a>' + contacts[i] + '</a></li>');
}

$(".wrapperDropdown span").addClass("dropdown").text("Select Friend").prependTo(".wrapperDropdown ul");
$(".wrapperDropdown ul").addClass("list");
$(".list").click(function() {
  $(".wrapperDropdown li").toggle(300);
})
$(".wrapperDropdown li").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown").html($(this).text())
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

.wrapperDropdown ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px
}

.wrapperDropdown span {
  font-size: small;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.wrapperDropdown ul li {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapperDropdown li {
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.wrapperDropdown ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="fa_header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <div class="wrapperDropdown"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зафиксируй высоту родительского блока и (при необходимости) задай overflow таким, чтобы скроллинга не появлялось:

```
.wrapperDropdown {
    height:38px;
    overflow:visible; /* если стояло что-то другое */
}
```